# How to check internet in wifi is there or not?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-internet

I am facing the issue,

Wifi is connected but internet is not there.

How to check that??

Please somebody help.

Comment: Good 1 . use try catch block and get exception

Comment: This problem happens when we parse or call API

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConnectivityManager` to detect it:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) Context.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo niWifi = wm.getConnectionInfo();
SupplicantState supState = niWifi.getSupplicantState();
if(supState == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {
    // internet is working
}
```

Comment: this code return true always if wifi is connected, I need to check in wifi if internet is not there?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that other than checking your Wifi interface if it is up and running, you can't actually know if you are *connected* to Internet. If your need is just to check if everything is up and running, you could try to retrieve a page (ex: www.google.com ) and be prepared to catch an exception if it's going to fail.

Feel free to tell me I'm an idiot ^_^"